# Linear and nonlinear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I get confused about the difference between linear and nonlinear system. Suppose that we have a linear system

\begin{equation}\label{1}
Ax=b \tag{1}
\end{equation}

with  $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$and we define the $x$ as a nonlinear function

\begin{equation}
x(t) = \sin(2\pi t) + \sin(3\pi t) \quad \text{where} \quad t=1,2,\dots,n \tag{2}
\end{equation}

my question is, does the linearity of the system (1) depends on the nature of $x$ ( that can be either linear or nonlinear function)?. In case that the system (1) stays always linear as long as it takes the form of $A x$ no matter how the $x$ is defined, is it possible to transform it to a nonlinear system by adding a nonlinear term ? A term like   $e^{x(t)}$ or $x(t)^{2}$ ? is the system $Ax(t) + e^{x(t)} =  b$ a nonlinear one or example?

Thank you for you explanations and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a linear system of equation, $x$ is the **vector of variables**. It is not a vector of functions, so speaking about $x(t)$ is not really sensible. In your writing, you first say that $x\in\mathbb R^n$, but then you use the term $x(t)$. This is nonsensical. $x$ can either be a vector, or it can be a function, but it cannot be both at the same time.

---

That said, "a linear system" is an ill-defined term. There are multiple mathematical concepts that are called "a linear system etc". For example, there are linear systems of differential equations but you probably aren't talking about those.

**A linear system of equations** is any set of linear equations. Any such set of equation can be written compactly as $Ax=b$ for some fixed matrix $A$ and some fixed vector $b$.

Comment: Thank you for you explanations !.  I have understood the meaning of linear system of equations, thank you !. If we suppose now that i have a  vector of nonlinear functions $x(t)$, is it possible to add a nonlinear term to the linear system $Ax(t)=b$ to get a nonlinear system of equations ? can you give me an example please ?

Comment: @john Any systems of equations that is not a linear system of equations is, by definition, a nonlinear system of equations...

Comment: ok clear a thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first consider a system of equations, where we have only *one* equation. Then it is called *linear* if it is of the form
$$
a_1x_1+\cdots +a_nx_n=b,
$$
for constants $a_i,b\in K$ and variables $x_i$. It is called *polynomial*, if it is of the form
$$
f(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)=0,
$$
for a polynomial $f\in K[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]$. For example,
$$
3z^2y^7-28xyz+17z-28xy+515=0
$$
in the variables $x,y,z$ and rational coefficients.

It is *non-linear* if it is not linear. Now a *system* of equations just means that we have several such equations, which we want to solve simultaneously.

For example, consider the following system of polynomial, non-linear equations
$$x+y+z=1$$ $$x^2+y^2+z^2=35$$ $$x^3+y^3+z^3=97$$

Comment: First of all i really appreciate your detailed explanation and your patience, thank you so much. If we back now please to my example, one equation would be defined as $a_{1}x(t_{1})+a_{2}x(t_{2})...+a_{10}x(t_{10})=b$ where $x(t) = \sin(2\pi t) + \sin(3\pi t)$ and this is a linear equation. My first question please is if i add for example a nonlinear function let's say $e^{x(t)}$, the linear equation becomes nonlinear right ?

Comment: What is $x(2)$? Is it a variable?  We need variables like $x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_n$.

Comment: sorry i mean $e^{x(t)}$ a function with respect to the time $t$, i rectified  my question.

Comment: To be honest Mr. Burde i would like to transform my linear system into a nonlinear one and i don't know exactly how to modify it or what to add in the system of equations. Sorry for my stupide questions and for my misunderstanding.

Comment: Read again the answer by 5xum, how to do this.

Comment: ok thank you for everything.